# How to know if need to wrap app in Provider? mobx 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I moved to mobx 6v & mobx-react 7v
and I want to ask if I need to wrap root node in Provider like before (for example):

```
<Provider {...stores}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={RootComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
</Provider>
```

```
"mobx": "^6.1.8"
"mobx-persist-store": "^0.5.30"
"mobx-react": "^7.1.0"
```

Comment: The provider pattern is a nice way to share mobx stores through the app. There is a section in the docs, dedicated to  React integration https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: @IvanV. I must use it? and what it does?

Comment: It enables you to access your store deep in the react component tree. You don't have to use it.

Comment: @IvanV. If I don't use Provider everything works the same? and what is mean deep inside?

Comment: Can you provide an example how you use Mobx with React?